# Go Lang Scan doesent scan for next line

Tags: go, scanning

This scanner dosent scan for the next line. I will explain it in more detail when you see results...

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var inputFileName string
    var write string

    fmt.Scanln(&inputFileName)

    //func Join(a []string, sep string) string
    s := []string{inputFileName, ".txt"}
    inputFileName = strings.Join(s, "")

    creator, err := os.Create(inputFileName)
    check(err)

    /*
     *Writing
     */

    fmt.Printf("The file name with %s what do you want to write?", inputFileName)
    fmt.Scanln(&write)
    if len(write) <= 0 {
        panic("Cant be empty")
    }

    byteStringWrite := []byte(write)
    //func (f *File) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error)
    fmt.Println("BYTE : ", byteStringWrite)
    fmt.Println("NONBYTE : ", write)
    _, errWriter := creator.Write(byteStringWrite)
    check(errWriter)

    /**
     *Reading File
     */

    read, errRead := ioutil.ReadFile(inputFileName)
    check(errRead)
    readString := string(read)
    fmt.Println("*******************FILE*********************")
    fmt.Println(readString)
}

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Sample.txt //My User Input
The file name with Sample.txt what do you want to write?Hello World
BYTE :  [72 101 108 108 111]
NONBYTE :  Hello
*******************FILE*********************
Hello
```

---

So Here you can see it dosent look for the space. Meaning after the space it automatically quits. Can someone help me figure out this problem? Thankyou.

### EDIT

Using [bufio.ReadString()](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString);

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "bufio"
)

func main() {
    var inputFileName string
    var write string

    bio := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    inputFileName, err := bio.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Println(inputFileName)

    //func Join(a []string, sep string) string
    s := []string{inputFileName, ".txt"}
    inputFileName = strings.Join(s, "")

    creator, err := os.Create(inputFileName)
    check(err)

    /*
     *Writing
     */

    fmt.Printf("The file name with %s what do you want to write?", inputFileName)
    fmt.Scanln(&write)
    if len(write) <= 0 {
        panic("Cant be empty")
    }

    byteStringWrite := []byte(write)
    //func (f *File) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error)
    fmt.Println("BYTE : ", byteStringWrite)
    fmt.Println("NONBYTE : ", write)
    _, errWriter := creator.Write(byteStringWrite)
    check(errWriter)

    /**
     *Reading File
     */

    read, errRead := ioutil.ReadFile(inputFileName)
    check(errRead)
    readString := string(read)
    fmt.Println("*******************FILE*********************")
    fmt.Println(readString)
}

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}
```

Results:

```
amanuel2:~/workspace/pkg_os/07_Practice $ go run main.go 
Sample
The file name with Sample
.txt what do you want to write?Something Else
BYTE :  [83 111 109 101 116 104 105 110 103]
NONBYTE :  Something
*******************FILE*********************
Something
```

Gives me correct .txt .. But same issue as above, it dosent take spaces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly what `fmt.Scanln` is supposed to do:

> Scan scans text read from standard input, storing successive
>   space-separated values into successive arguments. Newlines count as
>   space. It returns the number of items successfully scanned. If that is
>   less than the number of arguments, err will report why.

If you want to read a line of text use `bufio.Reader`:

```
bio := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

// in case you want a string which doesn't contain the newline
line, hasMoreInLine, err := bio.ReadLine()
s := string(line)    
fmt.Println(s)

// in case you need a string which contains the newline
s, err := bio.ReadString('\n')
fmt.Println(s)
```

Comment: How do i do that.. I went to pkg, but it isnt very understandble. Do i just do `bufio.Reader(&write)` ??

Comment: I added some you to the answer

Comment: I have updated my question. Your solution dosent work

Comment: Of course it works. Your application still contains `fmt.Scanln()` which is the reason it doesn't work as expected.